# PhpStorm Generic Classes not working at all

Tags: php, generics, phpstorm, phpdoc

This is all happening for me in PhpStorm 2022.2.1

I've been trying to set up a class in PHP that supports Generics, but to no avail. No matter what I tried, PhpStorm always type hints as `mixed`. Here is a pair of classes as an example:

```
/** @template T */
class MyGenericClass
{
    /** @var T */
    public $param;

    /** @param T $param */
    public function __construct($param)
    {
        $this->param = $param;
    }

    /** @return T */
    public function getParam()
    {
        return $this->param;
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static function test(): void
    {
        $generic = new MyGenericClass(1);
        $a = $generic->getParam();
        $b = $generic->param;
    }
}
```

I would expect `$generic->getParams()` and `$generic->param` to be hint typed as `int`, but both of these show up as `mixed`. I also tried adding a `@var MyGenericClass<int> $generic`, but it does not help, and PhpStorm warns that it's already inferred from source code.

I also tried to set this up with arrays, and I even tried using Symfony ArrayCollections that are supposed to work - passing an array of integers and calling `first()` on a Symfony ArrayCollection is hint typed as mixed too.

On the other hand, function scoped templates work just fine. If I make a function like

```
    /**
     * @template T
     * @param class-string<T> $param
     * @return T
     */
    public static function test2(string $param)
    {
        return new $param();
    }
```

the return type is hinted as `mixed|T`, and when passing an actual class string, it does correctly hint for result functions, although that seems to also be the case even if I get rid of templates. In a similar case, I had hint show up as the actual passed type, not sure why it's showing up as `T` instead of the Class string passed to it?

I'm not sure whether I'm missing something, or maybe something is messed up with my configuration?

Comment: This sounds like a bug you should report to PHPStorm (or [look for an existing one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=generics%20template))

Comment: What PhpStorm version are you using? Your code sample seems to work fine both on 2022.2.2 and in 2022.3 EAP 1. While in 2022.2.2, `$a` and `$b` are typed as  `int|mixed`, in 2022.3, [they're just `int`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ubq1KJrSU3LrCt5Mh_thC5piwv6UVpHd).

Comment: @EugeneMorozov as mentioned in the post it was all done on 2022.2.1 version. Updated to 2022.2.2. I can confirm $a and $b show up as int|mixed, though I was under the impression that the class property / function return type would also be hinted to be mixed|int or int, which it still just shows as mixed.

Comment: @AdamJacyno, I can confirm that; in [2022.3 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/), this is solved too